# how to insert multiple values using a for-loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This code below works with both a DAO and dBhelper class. I have 3 tables with approx 6 columns for each, but I'm fed up "playing" with the field names for every method (insert, delete and so on..) and would like to replace that code below **using a for-loop**, browsing both the field names and data to be inserted into the dB.

So the question is :
how to replace such an expression `MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID` to `MySQLiteHelper.columnName` sothat I can embed this oneliner into a `for-loop`.

```
private String[] allColumns = {
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_1,
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_2,
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_3
};
String[] mydata = myobject.getData();

// Here I would like to use a for-loop for the following lines
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_1, mydata[0]);
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_2, mydata[1]);
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_3, mydata[2]);
```

Comment: Not quite sure what your asking but I guess what I have is at least semi what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String[] allColumns = {
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_1,
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_2,
    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_level_3
};

String[] mydata = myobject.getData();

for(int i = 0; i < allColums.length(); i++){
    values.put(allColums[i], mydata[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thx, I'm so ashamed as I was trying to replace constant names.